# Maclaurin Series of $e^{t^2/2}$

Tags: taylor-expansion, proof-explanation

How do we find Maclaurin Series of $e^{t^2/2}$? I see one way on one book to do it is applying the fact that $e^x = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!}$, then $$e^{t^2/2} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(\frac{1}{2}t^2)^n}{n!}$$
But I cannot really understand why can we directly subsitute $\frac{1}{2}t^2$ into $e^x$ equation since it is not a constant. May someone explain to me? I am really confused.

Comment: It is due to the definition of $e^x$. Let $x=\frac{1}{2} t^2$ then substitute into the definition equation and we are done.

Comment: I'm not sure why it bothers you that $1/t^2$ is not a constant.  For any value of $t,$ it's just some number.  You substitute that into the formula for $e^x.$  That gives you a formula in terms of $t$.

Comment: Consider the what you do with function composition with more simple minded examples ... $f(x) = x^2 + 2.  f(e^x) = (e^x)^2 + 2$  You are doing the same thing into a function that is defined as an infinite series.

Comment: If you choose a value of $t$ it becomes a constant :D

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks a lot for the help.